# iteration on a mix of array and associative

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, scripting, associative-array

I have the following script:

```
declare -A as1
declare -A as2
declare -a arr=()
declare -A sup

as1[file]="file1"
as2[file]="file2"

echo "test: ${as1[file]} ${as2[file]}"

i=1
arr+=(as$i)
i=2
arr+=(as$i)

for index in "${arr[@]}";
do
   declare -n temp="$index"
   echo "${temp[file]}"
done

sup[arr]=$arr

echo "try to print:"
for el in "${!sup[@]}"
do
   item=${sup[$el]}
    for index in "${item[@]}";
    do
       declare -n temp="$index"
       echo "${temp[file]}"
    done
done
```

It basically build an associative array of an array. In the array there are two associative arrays.
I am not sure if it is too much complicated but it should work.
The problem is the output is the following:

```
test: file1 file2
file1
file2
try to print:
file1
```

where the last line 'file2' is missing. I suppose there is an error in the last loop but I can't catch it.
Any help?

## EDIT1

The following script:

```
declare -A as1
declare -A as2
declare -a arr=()
declare -A sup

as1[file]="file1"
as2[file]="file2"

echo "test: ${as1[file]} ${as2[file]}"

i=1
arr+=(as$i)
i=2
arr+=(as$i)

echo "test1:"
for index in "${arr[@]}";
do
   declare -n temp="$index"
   echo "${temp[file]}"
done

sup[arr]=arr

echo "test2:"
for el in "${sup[@]}" ; do
  declare -n items="$el"
  for item in "${items[@]}" ; do
    declare -n temp="$item"
    echo "${temp[file]}"
  done
done
```

makes the following output:

```
test: file1 file2
test1:
file1
file2
test2:
file1
file2
file1
file2
```

it seems it loops two times

## EDIT2

I am still have issues in applying this to a real case.
I have created the following directories and files:

```
for p in 1 2; 
do 
   mkdir -p "/tmp/tt/tt${p}"; 
   for t in 1 2; 
   do 
      touch "/tmp/tt/tt${p}/test${t}"
   done
done
```

I am using the following script:

```
declare -A sourceDirTree
create_source_directory_tree()
{        
      
   root_dir=$1
   
   j=1
   while read dir;
   do    
      declare -a siteFiles$j
      dir=${dir##*/}
      i=1   
      while read file;
      do 
         declare -A arrVar$j$i
         declare -A "arrVar$j$i[path]=$file"
         declare -a "siteFiles$j+=(arrVar$j$i)"
         ((i++))
      done <<< $(find ${root_dir}/${dir} -type f)
      arr=siteFiles$j
      for index in "${arr[@]}"
      do 
         declare -n temp="$index"
         echo "${temp[path]}"
      done
      sourceDirTree[$dir]="siteFiles$j"
      ((j++))
   done <<< $(find ${root_dir} -type d -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 2> /dev/null)  
} 

create_source_directory_tree /tmp/tt
```

the result I am getting is the following:

```
# ./test.sh 
siteFiles1 arrVar11
siteFiles2 arrVar21
```

and I am not getting why?
Could you please help me?

going more in details, the following example works:

```
declare -A sourceDirTree
create_source_directory_tree()
{        
      
   dir="/tmp/tt/tt1"
   
   declare -a siteFiles
   dir=${dir##*/}
   i=1   
   while read file;
   do
      echo "Processing file $file" 
      declare -A as$i
      declare -A "as$i[path]=$file"
      declare -a "siteFiles+=(as$i)"
      ((i++))
   done <<< $(find /tmp/tt/${dir} -type f)
   for index in "${siteFiles[@]}"
   do 
      declare -n temp="$index"
      echo "${temp[path]}"
   done
}
```

but the following does not work:

```
declare -A sourceDirTree
create_source_directory_tree()
{        
      
   dir="/tmp/tt/tt1"
   
   j=1
   declare -a siteFiles$j
   dir=${dir##*/}
   i=1   
   while read file;
   do
      echo "Processing file $file" 
      declare -A as$i
      declare -A "as$i[path]=$file"
      declare -a "siteFiles$j+=(as$i)"
      ((i++))
   done <<< $(find /tmp/tt/${dir} -type f)
   arr=siteFiles$j
   for index in "${arr[@]}"
   do 
      declare -n temp="$index"
      echo "${temp[path]}"
   done
}
```

it gives me the following output:

```
Processing file /tmp/tt/tt1/test1
Processing file /tmp/tt/tt1/test2
as1
```

Comment: `sup[arr]=$arr` assigns just the first element of `$arr`, and not the entire array. An associative array can't contain arrays, the values are just scalars in any case. You could do some trickery by stringifying your arrays to store them in the associative array, but there are no native nested arrays.

Comment: ShellCheck actually points this out: "Expanding an array without an index only gives the first element."

Answer (score 1):

`sup[arr]=$arr` is the same thing as `sup[arr]=$arr[0]`. You're only getting the first element of the array with that assignment. Bash's data structures in general are not that powerful. Arrays only map integers to strings, and associative arrays only map strings to strings. You can't nest data structures inside each other without resorting to hacks.

In this case you could store the name of the array in `sup` and use a name reference as you've done in other places.

```
sup[arr]=arr
# iterating items instead of indices here, if you really
# need the indices then use the ${!sup[@]} logic as you have 
for el in "${sup[@]}" ; do
  declare -n items="$el"
  for item in "${items[@]}" ; do
    declare -n temp="$item"
    echo "${temp[file]}"
  done
done
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @tjm3772, but I am getting the following output:
```
test: file1 file2
test1:
file1
file2
test2:
file1
file2
file1
file2
```
It looks it makes the loop two times

Comment: If I copy/paste the code you edited into your question I only get `test2: file1 file2`. Do you accidentally have an extra block of code somewhere?

Comment: See here: https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/Oaq

Comment: I think you are right! My bad!

Comment: Thanks! I am still having an issue in applying to real life case. Please check EDIT2. Thanks

Comment: @learning-man I think you're reaching a point where post a new question is better than continuing to edit more questions into your existing post. At a glance though `<<< $(find ${root_dir} -type d -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 2> /dev/null)` looks very suspicious. This is a Here String and means you're passing the entire output of find as one string. You probably want something more like `< <( find ${root_dir} -type d -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 2> /dev/null)` but a new question would give people an opportunity to elaborate on why and point out other possible issues with your code.

Comment: I found <<<$( in here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/402750/modify-global-variable-in-while-loop . Do you think it is not correct? In reality this is not in the Advanced Bash Scripting Guide ...

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution is the following:

```
arr=siteFiles$j[@]
for index in "${!arr}"
do
   declare -n temp="$index"
   echo "${temp[path]}"
done
```